# Argumentation, series and convergence

Tags: notation, convergence-divergence

Consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}$. We know that it converges.

Given $k\in\left(0,\infty\right)$. Is it then "okay" to say that there exists a $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n=j}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}<k$? Or does it need some extra argumentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always depends on the audience, but for an audience knowledgeable about sequences and series this should be obvious enough not to require further detailed arguments.

Comment: I agree since it is an elementary fact that a series converges only if its terms tend to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The fact $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{3}}$ that converges means that  converges the sequence of partial sums $S_N=\sum\limits _{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{3}}$